# Создание нового POST запроса + сохранение данных из старого

Tags: java, httpclient

Для авторизации на сайте пользуюсь таким вот кодом.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        try {
            HttpPost httpost = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.ru/takelogin.php");

            List <NameValuePair> nvps = new ArrayList <NameValuePair>();
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "Yourname"));
            nvps.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "Yourpasswd"));

            httpost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvps, HTTP.UTF_8));

            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httpost, responseHandler);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
            System.out.println(responseBody);
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------");

        } finally {
            httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
        }
```

Авторизация проходит успешно.

**Вопрос**:
как мне теперь передать новый пост запрос и не потерять статус авторизации?
Если создать новый `HttpPost httpost2 = new HttpPost("http://www.somesite.ru/takelogin.php");`,
то естественно сайт меня считает не авторизованным юзером =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно перенести cookies из первого запроса во второй.

Могу предположить, что вам нужны методы `DefaultHttpClient.getCookieStore()` и `DefaultHttpClient.setCookieStore()`.

Comment: Я всего день на Java пишу, и час как с HttpClient разобрался.. мнеб что-нить поконкретнее=)