# Отправить POST запрос с сохранением куков

Tags: java, android, post, cookie

Для авторизации на сайте пользуюсь таким вот кодом:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            BufferedReader reader = null;

            String l = null;
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");


            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.mysite.ru/api/?act=auth");

            try {

                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", ""+loginTextVod.getText()));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("passwd", ""+passwdTextVod.getText()));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));


                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "cp1251"), 8);

                while ((l = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    sb.append(l);
                }
                reader.close();
                return sb.toString();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            return null;
        }
```

Авторизируюсь успешно, но если отправлю другой пост-запрос, то сервер, естественно, скажет мне - "гуляй, ты не авторизован". Как сделать, чтоб куки сохранились? В xCode (objective-c) сохраняет само, в Java я еще новичок.

Вот подобный вопрос, но парню так и не помогли:

[Создание нового POST запроса + сохранение данных из старого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/84430/java-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-post-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE)

Comment: есть такая штука - google    
https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20post%20request%20save%20cookies&es_th=1

Comment: @metalurgus, гуглил весь день, не нашел рабочих способов, сделал вывод куков через getCookieStore(), сохранение их в SharedPreferences, и в другом активити вытаскиваю из SharedPreferences и добавляю через httppost.setHeader("Cookie", "PHPSESSID=" + cookiesPref2)

Comment: @SuperPonchik, по первой ссылке в поисковом запроссе, что я дал, есть правильный ответ. Вы не умеете гуглить.

Answer (score 1):

У меня почти похожий метод на ваш но он немного проще, я создавал класс, который выгружал тогда когда надо

```
package ux.project.chat.uchat;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class poster {

    String Version="Android Test Client 1.1";
    String Server="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public String poster(final List nameValuePairs) {

        final HttpPost http = new HttpPost(Server);
        final String[] temper = new String[1];
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    http.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,"utf-8"));
                    temper[0] = httpclient.execute(http, new BasicResponseHandler());
                    ;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    temper[0] = "Данные не пришли, возможно они затерялись, но мне не известно где они:(";

                    //Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    //bundle.putString("Key", temper[0]);

                    //Message msg = handler.obtainMessage();
                    //msg.setData(bundle);
                    //handler.sendMessage(msg);
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return temper[0];

    }


};
```

Класс рабочий, но проблема если соединения нету у него глючки начинаются и ему че-то в переменных массив понадобился.

И простите если класс не красиво написан или еще-что-то, я новичек в этом.